# Max / Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g, max, where-clause

I'm new to sql and have the following query.  There are multiple lines because a new line is added on the last day of each month.  What I want to do is select the record with the most recent accounting_dt.  I have been trying to use max on the accounting_dt field but keep getting errors.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  If there is a better way to write this query, I appreciate those comments as well.  As I said before, I'm new to this want am looking to learn the right way to do these things.  thanks again for your help.

```
  SELECT 
    pa.BUSINESS_UNIT,
    pdr.DEPTID,
    pa.IN_SERVICE_DT,
    pa.ASSET_ID,
    pa.DESCR,
    pb.LIFE,
    pb.METHOD,
    pdr.COST,
    pdr.DEPR,
    pdr.depr_ytd,
    pdl.accounting_dt

    from PS_ASSET pa,
    PS_BOOK pb,
    PS_DEPR_RPT pdr,
    PS_DIST_LN pdl

    where pa.BUSINESS_UNIT = 'A0056'
    and pa.ASSET_ID = '000000000003'
    and pb.BOOK = 'PERFORM'
    and pdr.book = 'PERFORM'
    and pdl.book = 'PERFORM'
    and pdr.FISCAL_YEAR = '2014'
    and pdr.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = '12'
    and pb.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID and pb.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT
    and pdr.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID and pdr.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT
    and pdl.ASSET_ID= pa.ASSET_ID and pdl.BUSINESS_UNIT = pa.BUSINESS_UNIT
    and pdl.distribution_type = 'DE'
```

RESULTS:

```
   BU    DEPTID  INSERVDT     IDNO            DSCR     LIFE   METH      COST      DEPREC
         ACCUMDP  ACCT_DT

A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  31-JAN-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  28-FEB-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  31-MAR-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  30-APR-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  31-JUL-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  31-JUL-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  30-JUN-14
A0056       01-JAN-14   000000000003    Test    72  SL  500 7.36    659.75  30-JUN-14
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about explicit `join` syntax.  It not only makes queries more readable, but it is more powerful notation.

I am guessing that you want the most recent record for each `BU`.  You can solve your problem using `row_number()`.  Here is an example of how to do that:

```
with t as (
      <your query goes here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by bu order by accounting_dt desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I'll give that a try and see if I can make it work.  Thanks again